# how can i have my page inherit from a class instead of a table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i need to access data from a table and from a view on a particular page, so i made a class that can access them both. looks like this `

```
namespace LoanManager.Models
{
    public class Loan_vwFieldValues
    {
        public Loan loan { get; set; }
        public VW_FIELD_VALUE vwFieldValues { get; set; }

    }
}
```

at the top of my page i have this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<LoanManager.Models.Loan_vwFieldValues>>" %>
```

then i have this my controller after some other other code that works.

```
return View(_db.LOAN_VWFIELDVALESs.Where(predicate));
```

and my definition for that looks like this.

```
public System.Data.Linq.Table<Loan_vwFieldValues> LOAN_VWFIELDVALESs
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Loan_vwFieldValues>();
            }
        }
```

this works fine for all the rest of my pages (they have different names of course), but they are not a class, they just reference one table or a view i have made, but this page needs to access a table and a view, but it complains when it gets to this last part of posted code(return statement) and says that Loan_vwFieldValues is not mapped as a table, which is true because it is NOT a table,
i also have this to fill the Loan_vwFieldValues

```
public ActionResult LoanProperties(int id)
    {
        Loan_vwFieldValues l = new Loan_vwFieldValues();

        l.loan = (from a in _db.Loans where a.LOAN_ID == id select a).First();
        l.vwFieldValues = (from v in _db.VW_FIELD_VALUEs where v.Loan_ID == id select v).First();

        return View(l);

    }
```

but how can i get this to work with my class?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify...Why are we retrieving something that is not a table as if it were? Wouldn't it make more sense to create a new class that matches what you want, and then use that for the page instead of using a table-that-isn't-a-table?

Comment: @guildsbounty - he correctly did define such a class (Loan_vwFieldValues) and correctly references it in his page.  He's not creating objects of that type though...

Comment: yes, what i dont know if how to create objects of type "my class", i cannot find an example or sintax anywhere pls help, or send me to a tutorial or something where i can learn how i can accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a collection of Loan_vwFieldValues and return *that*.  We don't have enough information to tell you how to construct those objects from your data access layer.

In other words...

```
return View(_db.LOAN_VWFIELDVALESs.Where(predicate).Select(
  x => new Loan_vwFieldValues()
  {
     loan = yourCodeHere,
     vwFieldValues = moreOfYourCodeHere
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks every one that helped, i found the solution by doing the following... i hope it can help others as well.

```
IQueryable<Loan> loanList = _db.Loans.Where(predicate);

List<Loan_vwFieldValues> loanVwList = new List<Loan_vwFieldValues>();

foreach (Loan loan in loanList)
{
    Loan_vwFieldValues loanVw = new Loan_vwFieldValues();
    loanVw.loan = loan;
    loanVw.vwFieldValues = (from n in _db.VW_FIELD_VALUEs where n.Loan_ID == loan.LOAN_ID select n).First();
    loanVwList.Add(loanVw);
}

return View(loanVwList);
```